# Upload Certificate to App Service from key Vault

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, app-service-environment

In Azure Key Vault Certificate will be auto renewed nearer to expiry date.
 would like to know how can renewed certificate be uploaded to App-Service/ Azure Functions.

Is there a hook available on KeyVault to listen for Certificate successful recreation. so Thumbprint and renewed certificate will be updated to App Service.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such hook. You can use azure powershell\cli\rest api\whatever to retrieve the certificate and push it to the app service. You can configure Azure Function\Runbook to do that on a schedule, so you dont have to worry about it.

Rest Api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate
Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-ssl-certificate
Azure Cli: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-configure-ssl-certificate