# I want to be able to add/upload a certificate to my Azure Web App from my Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to automate this process where I am uploading my certificate to my Web App.

I came across **New-AzWebAppSSLBinding** which enables upload but also binds the certificate to the web app.

I was trying it like so -

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WebAppName $webAppName -Thumbprint "" -Name "certificatetest"
```

However, it gives an error because the domain is not set in the Web App.

I do not want to bind the certificate. I just want to be able to automate certificate upload through powershell. Is there an alternate way to do this?

I have already found this:
[Upload Certificate to App Service from key Vault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804342/upload-certificate-to-app-service-from-key-vault),
but it doesn't help much and I was hoping there is an ARM independent process through powershell?

Comment: i could have sworn this automatically always used the latest version of the certificate in keyvault? i might be mistaken tho: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#import-a-certificate-from-key-vault

Comment: What do you mean `there is an ARM independent process `? Is that you just want to know how to upload the certificate through PowerShell without configuring ssl?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, Azure PowerShell module does not provide any command used to upload SSL certificate to Azure Web APP. It just provides command used to upload SSL certicifate and bind SSL. So if you just want to upload SSL certificate to Azure Azure Web APP, I suggest you use Azure CLI. We can use CLI command `az webapp config ssl upload` to implement it. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/ssl?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-config-ssl-upload).

Besides, if you just want to implemrnt it with Azure PowerShell, please refer to the following script

```
Connect-AzAccount


#get app service plan which you want to associate the certificate with 
$planName="stanQnA"
$planGraoup="stan"
$plan =Get-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName $planGraoup -Name $planName


#Get cert content
$pfxpassword="Password0123!"
$pfxpath="E:\Cert\example.pfx"
$pfxFileBytes = get-content $pfxpath -Encoding Byte
$pfxblob=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($pfxFileBytes)


$properties=@{
 pfxBlob =$pfxblob;
 serverFarmId=$plan.Id;
 password=$pfxpassword;


}

New-AzResource -Location $plan.Location -ResourceName "cert" -ResourceType "Microsoft.Web/certificates" -ResourceGroupName "jimtest"-Properties $properties -Force
```

[image]

Comment: According to your code, it is just uploading a local certificate to the location. How would I just upload this certificate to a web app?

Comment: @user3305209 The script is used to uplaod certificate  to azure app service. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/certificates/createorupdate